# Does scikit have an equivalent creation for TensorFlow's tf.feature_column.crossed_column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

So TensorFlow has crossed feature columns which can be explained here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide#intersecting_multiple_columns_with_crossedcolumn. In short, we may want to create a new class that shows a correlation between any number of combinations of existing base classes.

Does scikit have an equivalent function that makes it easy to add the cross column to numpy.ndarray, scipy.sparse.csr_matrix, or pandas.dataframe object?

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists in `sklearn`. However, for numerical features you could probably use `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures` to the same effect. For non-numerical features, you could implement something similar to `crossed_column` by simply concatenating the string features (you could also hash them similar to the description [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/crossed_column) but I'm not sure that's necessary outside of performance concerns).